EKS- Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "arn::x/xx" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
Running into

Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/xx" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope

When trying
kubectl get ns

I have tried this

Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden - AWS EKS

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-object-access-error

The IAM role I'm trying to access the EKS cluster has the permission of



the EKS-admin has the permission of "Full Access" for all resources




My terraform has access to the ARN (example below)
manage_aws_auth_configmap = true

aws_auth_users = [
  {
    userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:root"
    username = "root"
    groups   = ["system:masters"]
  },
  {
    userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user"
    username = "xx"
    groups   = ["system:masters"]
  },
]

aws_auth_accounts = [
  "xxxxx"
]

and I also verified the cluster has ConfigMap by running this command on the amazon cloud shell
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapAccounts: |
    - "xxxxx"
  mapRoles: |
    - "groups":
      - "system:bootstrappers"
      - "system:nodes"
      "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/backend-eks-node-group-xxxxxxxxxx"
      "username": "system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}"
  mapUsers: |
    - "groups":
      - "system:masters"
      "userarn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:root"
      "username": "root"
    - "groups":
      - "system:masters"
      "userarn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user"
      "username": "xx"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-11-27T13:33:15Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "26180451"
  uid: 13b72acd-5531-4fde-9a2c-43df456704e1

I also tried creating a new a new IAM user and giving full access and tried connecting to the EKS.

Are you sure you need a role? The ConfigMap shows a user.

Also, by assigning the IAM policies to a user you don't actually allow the user to perform any Kubernetes actions, i.e, to use kubectl. For that you need to define a Role or a ClusterRole and assign permissions.

The answer to this question is actually two-fold. The first part that is important to understand is that the permissions assigned to an IAM user/role are related to permissions in AWS. EKS permissions do not have anything to do with Kubernetes permissions. The former allow a user/role to interact with the AWS managed service (i.e, get the cluster information) when using AWS console/APIs/AWS CLI. The latter, i.e, Kubernetes permissions, allow you to interact with the cluster, but when using kubectl. By using the ConfigMap, the connection between an IAM user/role and a Kubernetes Role/ClusterRole can be achieved. For that to work, you would have to create a Role/ClusterRole and bind it to a Kubernetes user/group. The way you can do that depends on your use case, but it can also be achieved with terraform.
resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_v1" "some_role" {
  metadata {
    name = "some-role-name"
  }

  rule {
    api_groups = [""]
    resources  = ["namespaces"]
    verbs      = ["get", "list"]
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding_v1" "some_role_binding" {
  metadata {
    name = "some-role-name-binding"
  }

  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name      = kubernetes_cluster_role_v1.some_role.metadata[0].name
  }

  subject {
    kind = "User"
    name = "xx" # or whatever the user name is
  }
}

This way, the ClusterRole gets created, and it will be bound to the group "system:masters" with the EKS configuration and to the user you created:
aws_auth_users = [
  {
    userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:root"
    username = "root"
    groups   = ["system:masters"]
  },
  {
    userarn  = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user"
    username = "xx"
    groups   = ["system:masters"]
  },
]

If you need to limit the access to a particular namespace, you could use the RoleBinding instead of ClusterRoleBinding. Alternatively, you could crate a Role and use RoleBinding if you need additional security. Also, the rules in this example allow only listing namespaces, so if needed additional rules can be added.
As a final step, you would need to update the kube config file by using the aws eks update-kubeconfig <options> command.
NOTE: The above applies when the old way of EKS authentication is used (i.e ConfigMap). The new way with using EKS API to authenticate solves some of the issues mentioned previously, first and foremost mapping between IAM users/roles, policies, and Kubernetes permissions.


Not all EKS variant supports access entries at this time of writing, eg. Outposts.

Of course, but as far as I could tell from the question, the EKS module with the ConfigMap authentication is used.

Your answer is perfect. But aws-auth is not deprecating, at least not now or anytime soon.

Haha, thanks, I just posted what is written in the AWS docs, don't shoot the messenger. :D
